# Straining seeds from jam

Tags: food-safety

I have a jar of real fruit jam, made without pectin, it tastes fantastic but the berry seeds are extremely hard. Can I reheat it in a pot on the stove and strain out the seeds and put it back in the jar and keep it refrigerated?

Answer (score 5):

For a jam, (assuming with fruit solids), be aware that since you will have to force it through a strainer whether you warm it up or not, it will lose some of it's fruity texture. But it will taste the same. It will be easier if you warm it, but do NOT let it get hot enough to steam or bubble. And yes, keep refrigerated.

My reference is 65 years of making my own.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you expand on the reasoning to not let it steam or bubble? I know the bubbling would be a result of boiling, hence more cooking, but steaming would only require a low heat.

Comment: Presumably because once it steams, it's loosing water and changing the overall consistency. This could cause it to set harder than before